# Liferay export user into Ldap: Password policy

Tags: ldap, liferay, password-encryption

I have this problem:

I have enabled Liferay to import and export users from/to **OpenLDAP** server.

When I create a user in Liferay I obtain this page:

[image]

So, I have create a new user and Liferay has assigned to it a password (**3zbPk6KA**).

But.. if I try to login with new user (and generated password) I obtain the error message of incorrect credentials. In LDAP server I can see the new account but, the corresponding password seems to be different from that generated by Liferay..

In Java console i read this warning:

```
14:20:15,882 WARN [http-bio-8080-exec-6][LDAPAuth:208] Passwords do not match for userDN cn=myUser,ou=users,dc=myProject,dc=com
```

Some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem too. what's your value for Ldap password policy and what's your liferay version ?

I think you have 2 options :

1. Disable Ldap password policy, and if your Liferay version has no bug on exporting new user's autogenerated passwords, Your scenario is supposed to work. Else, you'll have to create a patch/hook that sends that password to LDAP
2. Enable LDAP password policy, setup a fixed default LDAP password,  and hook the login process, so that you inform the new registered user (Screen Message + validation email) on her initial password. Note that there's still a security issue here, because of the fixed password, as someone could create accounts for other users if he knows their e-mails and tries to register before them.

Comment: I use liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2 and I disabled the password LDAP policy option

Answer (score 0):

You have to unmark "required" in controlpanel→portal→configuration→autenticathion→LDAP to di

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that specific scenario doesn't work. I have used Liferay 6.1 and know there are a number of bugs with the LDAP function of version 6.1. The problem that I faced was that checking "Use LDAP Password Policy" resulted in a user being created without a password.

However, if your password is being created in Liferay, you can turn off the export in Liferay LDAP wizard and programmatically export users through a hook using Java LDAP look up. I had to do it and it fixed a number of similar issues for me.

The link is a below
http://abhirampal.com/2014/12/20/liferay-ldap-export-to-active-directory-disabled-user-bug/