# Liferay and user password during the export into OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap, liferay, openldap, password-hash

I have a question about Liferay.

I have configuate my system with Liferay + Jasig CAS Authentication and OpenLDAP.
I can authenticate my user correctly and I can import user account from LDAP (Ldap import).

I have also configurate the user export to OpenLDAP..so, now I can export an account when this will be create. 
Infact I can see this new account in my OpenLDAP server.

When Liferay create a new account it generate a random password for this new account (for example 4hdsdsh) and the user receive an e-mail after the registration.

The problem is: I my OpenLDAP server this password does not seem to be equal to the one just generated by Liferay..
So, the new user will never be able to authenticate into my Liferay (because I use CAS + LDAP).

I also found a funny/strange thing: If I modify this new password in Liferay (using an administrator account) I see this password correctly into my OpenLDAP server and so, the user can finally log into my Liferay..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Liferay export user into Ldap: Password policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963190/liferay-export-user-into-ldap-password-policy)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but it seems while user registration it is just exporting the fields entered by user in registration screen and since the password is auto generated after registration, it is not exported to LDAP and might be blank till User has not updated his password by Logging in.

You can debug this class PortalLDAPExporterImpl.Java and also watch user detail in LDAP via jxplorer whats the password & user status as well. If password is blank you could extend class and your logic to pass auto generated or default password for first time case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug of Liferay:

- See following issue: https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-43045